# remove part of string from each line

Tags: regex, linux, shell, unix, command-line

I have a text file, where each line is a single string of the format

```
/home/usr1/284.txt
```

The whole file is like

```
/home/usr1/284.txt
/home/usr1/361.txt
```

What I want is to remove `/home/usr1/` and keep the file name, e.g., `284.txt`

How to do that using linux/unix command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use Perl, like so:

```
perl -pe 's,.*/,,' file.txt
```

Comment: thanks, can you elaborate how does the regular expression of 's,.*/,,' work?

Comment: @bit-question, it removes everything up to and including the last `/`. `s` means substitution, `,` is the delimiter I chose, but could have used any other character, `.*/` is the regex it self, and empty string as the replacement. You can use almost any character as the delimiter, could have written `s!.*/!!` for example.

Answer (score 7):

```
sed -e 's!/home/usr1/!!' filename.txt
```

or

```
awk -F\/ {print $NF} filename.txt
```

should do the trick. Note the use of `!` instead of the more usual `/` as pattern delimiters in the `sed` example - it means you don't have to escape literal `/` characters in your pattern.

Answer (score 6):

Since the fields in the file are fixed, you can simply do:

```
cut -b 12-
```

To skip the first 11 bytes of the input.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while read line; do basename "$line"; done < filename
```

The reciprocal of `basename` is `dirname`, in case you need the other part eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Got bash?

```
read -d '' -a lines < input.txt
echo "${lines[@]##*/}"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one way to do it (TIMTOWTDI). In addition to the existing answers, I can think of two ways of going about this:

1. Use slash "/" as a field delimiter: reverse, cut the first field, then reverse again:

   ```
   < filename.txt rev | cut -d/ -f 1 | rev
   ```
2. These are filenames, hence you can use GNU `basename` in combination with `xargs` (or GNU [`parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)) to, as you say, "keep the file name":

   ```
   < filename.txt xargs basename -a
   ```

   or

   ```
   < filename.txt parallel -X basename -a
   ```